# How can i use controllers in radio group in flutter?

Tags: flutter, controller, radio-button

I am trying to get user input data with different types such as text data and radio button grouped data.

In text type inputs, i use TextEditingControllers, for example ;

```
final quantNumberController = TextEditingController();

String quant = quantNumberController.text;
var data = {'quant': quant, 'capp': capp}
```

...

```
  Container(
      width: 280,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: TextField(
        controller: quantNumberController,
        autocorrect: true,
        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter location'),
      )
  ),
```

And i want to receive radio button data like below, but is there any way to use controllers within ListTiles or how can i get user choice to my json data ;

```
  Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 10),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Location'),
          ListTile(
            title: const Text('First value'),
            leading: Radio(
              value: Cap.Cap33,
              groupValue: _capp,
              onChanged: (Capp value) {
                setState(() {
                  _capp = value;
                  capp = 'Cap33';
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: const Text('Second value'),
            leading: Radio(
              value: Capp.Cap22,
              groupValue: _capp,
              onChanged: (Capp value) {
                setState(() {
                  _capp = value;
                  capp = 'Cap22';
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: const Text('Third value'),
            leading: Radio(
              value: Capp.Cap44,
              groupValue: _capp,
              onChanged: (Capp value) {
                setState(() {
                  _capp = value;
                  capp = 'Cap44';
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ) ,
  ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the user choice is saved in `_capp`.

Let's make a new one:

```
int every_many_days;
RadioListTile<int>(
    title: Text('Every Day'),
    value: 1,
    groupValue: every_many_days,
    onChanged: (int value){
      setState(() {every_many_days = value;});
    },
),
RadioListTile<int>(
    title: Text('Every Week'),
    value: 7,
    groupValue: every_many_days,
    onChanged: (int value){
      setState(() {every_many_days = value;});
    },
),
```

Now the choice is available in the variable `every_many_days`, it will be **1** or **7**, and you don't need a controller.